# Using Max() in where clause in Presto SQL

Tags: sql, presto

I have the below table.

| ID | Desc | progress | updated_time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | abcd | planned | 2022-04-20 10:00AM |
| 1 | abcd | planned | 2022-04-25 12:00AM |
| 1 | abcd | in progress | 2022-04-26 4:00PM |
| 1 | abcd | in progress | 2022-05-04 11:00AM |
| 1 | abcd | in progress | 2022-05-06 12:00PM |

I just want to return a row that has the latest updated_time regardless of what progress it is in, which is,

| ID | Desc | progress | updated_time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | abcd | in progress | 2022-05-06 12:00PM |

I know if I group by 'progress' (as shown below), I will get one for planned too which I do not need. I just need a single row for each ID with its latest updated time.

I wrote the following query,

```
select ID,desc,progress,updated_time 
from t1 
where updated_time IN (select ID, desc, progress, max(updated_time) 
from t1 group by 1,2,3)
```

I get the following error too,
'Multiple columns returned by subquery are not yet supported'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Selecting multiple values in subquery won't work, you need to select single value with [scalar subquery](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/sql/select.html?highlight=subquery#scalar-subquery):

```sql
-- sample data
WITH dataset (ID, Desc, progress, updated_time) AS (
    VALUES 
(1, 'abcd', 'planned',  timestamp '2022-04-20 10:00'),
(1, 'abcd', 'planned',  timestamp '2022-04-25 12:00'),
(1, 'abcd', 'in progress',  timestamp '2022-04-26 16:00'),
(1, 'abcd', 'in progress',  timestamp '2022-05-04 11:00'),
(1, 'abcd', 'in progress',  timestamp '2022-05-06 12:00'),
(1, 'abcd', 'in progress',  timestamp '2022-05-07 12:00'),
(2, 'abcd', 'in progress',  timestamp '2022-05-04 11:00'),
(2, 'abcd', 'in progress',  timestamp '2022-05-06 12:00')
) 

--query
select  id, Desc, progress, updated_time
from dataset o
where updated_time = (select max(updated_time) from dataset i where i.id = o.id)
```

Or similar approach with `max` window function and subselect:

```sql
--query
select  id, Desc, progress, updated_time
from (
    select *,  max(updated_time) over (partition by id) max_time
    from dataset
)
where max_time = updated_time
```

Or just using `row_number`:

```sql
select  id, Desc, progress, updated_time
from 
(
    select *,  
        row_number() over(partition by id order by updated_time desc) rank
    from dataset
)
where rank  = 1
```

Output:

| id | Desc | progress | updated_time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | abcd | in progress | 2022-05-07 12:00:00.000 |
| 2 | abcd | in progress | 2022-05-06 12:00:00.000 |

Comment: All of them worked! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

I would probably use row_number or some other ranking function for this.

```
with t as (select a.*,
 row_number() over (partition by id order by updated_time desc as rn) 
select * from t where rn = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You are try for matching a single value with several columns  and yhis raise an error ..

Looking to you code for you goal, instead o f an IN clasue based on  a subquery you should use  inner join

```
select ID,desc,progress,updated_time 
from t1 
INNER JOIN 
( select ID, desc, progress, max(updated_time) max_time 
from t1 group by 1,2,3) t on t.max_time = t1.updated_time
```